# PostreSQL with PgPool running extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I'm running tests on PostgreSQL to see if it would be a feasible replacement for MySQL on a rather busy server.  I have the following configuration:

```
POSTGRESQL
max_connections = 10

PGPOOL
num_init_children = 8
max_pool = 100
```

I have a feeling my setup is less then optimal since benchmarking is proving it to be extremely slow.

Running `ab -c 50 -n 10000` took **over 15 minutes**

Whereas the same test, on the same server but connecting to MySQL takes only 1 second!

NOTE:
Each ab request is an insert statement.
Aslo I have changed the settings to the following, but the results have not improved

```
POSTGRESQL
max_connections = 100

PGPOOL
num_init_children = 32
max_pool = 4
```

The hardware has 12GB RAM and Intel Xeon 2.40GHz.

Comment: `max_connections = 10` is too low. You should raise that to at least 50 (or just keep the default of 100)

Comment: Is `ab` a write-heavy or read-heavy workload? Lots of small transactions or fewer bigger ones? Is there anything informative in PostgreSQL's logs? If you bypass PgPool, do you get a different result?

Comment: 10000 single insert statements per second is a lot. What kind of hardware (storage) do you use? Using default configuration, MySQL lies about it's performance, it's just caching the data and writes later. Until then, the data isn't safe. On the other hand, 10000 inserts in 15 minutes is way too slow, there is also something wrong.